# Singular curves and normalization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over a base field of characteristic zero (maybe not necessary).

If we identify two points $p_1,p_2$ on $X$ to define a singular nodal curve $Y$, i.e., $Y := X \backslash \{p_1,p_2\} \cup \{Q\}$, is $Y$ still projective?

Also, would $X$ naturally be the normalization of $Y$? It seems to be the case since we can define the normalization map $X \rightarrow Y$ to be the identity everywhere except at $p_1,p_2$, and send these two points to $Q \in Y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. All separated and finite type schemes over a field of dimension $\leq 1$ are quasi-projective; any irreducible separated finite type scheme over a field of dimension $1$ is either affine or projective. As $Y$ is not affine (a nonconstant global function would pull back to a nonconstant global function on $X$), it is projective. None of this requires characteristic zero, either.

$X$ is indeed the normalization of $Y$. The map $X\to Y$ is birational, and the map from the normalization of $Y$ to $Y$ is birational. Thus $X$ and the normalization of $Y$ are birational, but for smooth curves birational is the same as isomorphic. (I would maybe quibble with the way you're getting that map, but everything will ultimately work out, so maybe I should be quiet about that.)

Comment: Sorry if the question is silly but how does what you wrote in parentheses in the first paragraph imply that $Y$ is not affine? Also, for the second paragraph, what should be the correct way to get the normalization map?

Comment: If $Y$ is affine, it has nonconstant global functions. Such a function would pull back to a nonconstant global function on $X$ via the quotient map, since that map is surjective. But $X$ does not have any nonconstant global functions, because it is integral and projective. Therefore $Y$ could not have had any nonconstant global functions in the first place, and cannot be affine.

Comment: For normalization, the typical way is to define on every affine open a map given by taking the integral closure in the fraction field and then show these patch together (this compatibility is proven once, for all time, for every normalization, so it's not like something you have to do every day). My complaint is that just defining things on points is sometimes playing a little fast and loose, but it does work out here and it's not so bad in this case, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed replies, just one last question: if we were to identify 3 points on a curve instead, how many nodes do we get? Visually I would think its 1 but somehow I feel it should be 2.

Comment: Three identified points would no longer be a node, so I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Then what sort of singularity would that be? I guess if we identify $n$ points together on a curve, we should only obtain one singularity?

Comment: In general it's called a multiple point or an $r$-fold point (a node is an ordinary double point). And the procedure you described does produce only one singular point.